Расчет времени доставки в карточке товара Django
Пишу интернет магазин на django. Стоит следующая задача - в карточке товара выводить время доставки СДЭК, Boxberry, EMS, DPD. Как это лучше всего сделать? Каждый раз отправлять запросы api при рендере страницы - как по мне не самый лучший подход.

Очевидно, сохранить эту информацию где-нибудь
